# Multiple Submits on a page

Tags: php, if-statement, submit

I have this PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT distinct om_quote_no from `porders` order by om_quote_no desc") or die(mysql_error());
echo '<select name="project_no">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value=".$row['om_quote_no'].">".$row['om_quote_no']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
?>  
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="table">
<?php
                if($_GET){
```

So as you can see the PHP is forming a dropdown input and once submitted its going to execute some code, but what i need to do is have two dropdown inputs and therefore two submit buttons, however i'm not sure how to form the PHP if statement to distinguish which submit was pressed, so i'll have(pseudo):

```
if (submit1){

}

if (submit2){

}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your `<input type="submit">` elements names, the one that is clicked will have its name and value sent to the server.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit1">
```

if clicked will send `submit1=Submit` to the server.  You could therefore check with `if ($_GET['submit1'])` to see if it was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best way but can do something like this too:

```
<select name="test" onchange="document.location ='test.php?submit=dropdown1'">
<option>test</option>
<option>test1</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<select name="test1" onchange="document.location ='test.php?submit=dropdown2'">
<option>test2</option>
<option>test3</option>
</select>
```

within test.php file:

```
if($_GET['submit'] == 'dropdown1')
{
    print "One";
    //statements to execute
}elseif($_GET['submit'] == 'dropdown2'){
    //statements here to execute
    print "Two";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit 1" name="submit1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit 2" name="submit2"/>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
//do stuff
//grab select option
$select_option=$_POST['project_no'];

}else if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
//do stuff
}else{
//do stuff
}

?>
```

Or if your method is GET than change $_POST to $_GET :)